# Class vs. Type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just recently started to teach myself how to code.  I am currently reading *Think Python 2* for python 3 and when it teaches about the `type()` function, it gives the example `type(2)` which outputs `<class 'int'>`.  It then states that "the word 'class' is used in the sense of a category; a type is a category of values."

The part that confuses me is that the `type()` function outputs class instead of type. Also, I'm not sure about the difference between type and class; are string, float point, and integer classes of the type "value", or are they the same thing?

Comment: Python 3 completed the unification of types and classes (which [started way back with Python 2.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/)). Your book attempts to explain a difference that isn't really there anymore.

Comment: Basically a type is class that inherits from `object`.  In Python3, all classes inherit from `object`, so they are the same thing.

Comment: @zondo: that's not quite accurate either. It is related, but that's not a classification I'd use.

Comment: Maybe find another book...

Comment: @RickTeachey, what book would you suggest then?

Comment: The book I learned with, Learn Python the Hard Way, is a little old now since it was written for python 2.6. I'm not sure what good beginner books out there are worth using since I haven't been a beginner for a while, but I would suggest something that was written with Python 3 in mind.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Once upon a time, Python had both *types* and *classes*. Types were built-in objects defined in C; classes were what you built when using a `class` statement. The two were named differently because you couldn't mix these; classes could not extend types.

This difference was artificial, a limitation in the language implementation. [Starting with Python 2.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/), the developers of Python have slowly moved towards unifying the two concepts, with the difference all but gone in Python 3. Built-in types are now also labelled classes, and you can extend them at will.

Your book is trying to explain a difference that isn't present in Python anymore. Even in Python 2 the difference is only there in name, since `type(2)` shows the word 'type' is still used there:

```
>>> type(2)
<type 'int'>
```

but you can subclass `int` just like any other class.

(Python 2 does still have old-style classes, those that don't inherit from `object`; these are a remnant of the old system from before the unification.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "defined in C?"  So in Python 2, the type would be integer and the class would be 2?

Comment: @Jeff: For CPython (the default Python implementation you download from python.org), the implementation for the `int` type is done in C code, as opposed to user-created classes in Python code.

Comment: @Jeff: `2` is an *instance* of the type `int`. There are no classes involved there. But `class Foo: pass` defines a user-defind class object. `Foo()` would be an instance of that class.

Comment: @Jeff: basically, the terms `type` and `class` are interchangeable, but in older Python versions there was a difference still in that you could not mix the two.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand everything correctly, type was something defined by Python whereas a class was user created. In python 3, this doesn't matter because types and classes are unified. When you say C code, are you referring to C#/C++ or something else. I appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: @Jeff: Correct on `type` vs `class`. I am referring to [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)). C# and C++ both have been *named after C* (and both borrow heavily from that language as a basis for their own design).

Comment: So, does this mean that Python is built of C Programming Language? So when I hit execute, the interpreter is not taking what I have written and making it machine code, but rather translating/compiling to C which is then changed to machine code? Sorry to keep asking question.

Comment: If the difference is "all but gone" in Python 3, that means there is still some tiny vestige of difference left. I am completely confident I will never encounter this difference myself in my own code, but I'm still interested in what that tiny bit of difference is, for an academic conversation I'm having with a language enthusiast. What's that difference, or where can I read about it?

Comment: @JohnY: just terminology; `type()` is metaclass object that produces classes; `type(instance)` gives you the class of the object. The terms have become interchangeable almost. That's it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you could please go a bit further with clarifying internals, so things like `2` and `'abc'` are instances of their types, i.e `int` and `str`, so they are python objects that have methods, attributes, addresses, etc. If you were to do something like `import sys; sys.getsizeof('a')` you won't get 1 byte as as one would properly expect for utf-8 encoded strings but where are the actual values stored? like for instance the numerical value of `2`, or the numerical value of `'abc'` (since everything boils down to hex and binary in the end) ? how are they stored and used ?

Comment: @George: sorry, not in comments here. That's been answered elsewhere here on Stack Overflow, by me and others.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure thing, sry...I'll dig deeper for those answers! I'm actually curious about how that works internally.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I really appreciate this explanation, because PEP 483 had me confused, as it is asserting "the distinction between classes and types" https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#types-vs-classes

Answer (score 7):

The python hierarchy is Type (Metaclass) -> Class -> Instance.
Think of the function `type()` as going one level up.

If you use the function `type()` on an instance of an `int` (any integer) like so: `type(123)` you will receive the class of the instance which in this case is `int`. If you will use `type()` on the class `int`, you will recieve `type type` which is the metaclass of int.

Keep in mind metaclasses are advanced technical details of python and you do not need to learn about them at first.

Comment: The text in question is not referencing metaclasses. `type` is a metaclass, yes, but `type(someobject)` doesn't return the metaclass, it returns the class for that object. Bringing metaclasses into this only serves to confuse the matter further, I fear.

Comment: True that it's not referencing metaclasses but keep in mind type(obj) does return the metaclass of the object in case the object is itself a class. It's causes a bit of confusion, I agree, and that's why I wrote that it's more advanced but the solution is more complete like that I believe.

Comment: Yup, and then there is the fun with `type(type)`, etc. But that's all *too much information* that isn't really relevant to the question *what is the difference between a class and a type*?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input, will be more careful next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting to learn about programming, keep in mind that the terms "type" and "class" are heavily overloaded (used for sometimes different, sometimes synonymous things in different contexts).  Rougly speaking, you have...

- The abstract notion of *type*.  This is something that does not exist when the program runs, but a compiler (or you) can use them to identify invalid uses of objects
- In many languages, including python, there is a *runtime* representation of the *types*.  Using these representations to alter runtime behavior is called "reflection."
- Then there are *classes*.  So typically (in math), a *type* refers only to the structure of the data (i.e. fields and their types).  In Object Oriented Programming, it is typically necessary to keep the definitions of certain function local to the definition of the class to enforce "data-hiding."  Anyways, the end result is that we can conceptualize a *class* as a sort of "*type* McMenu".  You get a *type* (data-structure), interface (public methods), and constructor (usually given by some special syntax or convention - e.g. `__init__`).
- Finally, bear in mind that there are *static* and *dynamic* types of expressions.  The distinction that is relevant to programmers here is the notion of "virtual functions."  These don't feel that impressive in python, but in strong-er-ly typed languages like `C++` and `C#` this is rather powerful and helpful.