# Why Python2 shows <type 'int'> and Python3 shows <class 'int'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am learning Python through a video tutorial and tutor is using Python2. I am using Python3 to test and learn the code.
In this process I have noticed the difference:

```
Python2: type(10)
<type 'int'>
Python3: type(10)
<class 'int'>
```

Is this a change only to remove the ambiguity that 'int' is a class and not 'type'? as type is a metaclass. Saying so, I am not aware what metaclass is all about, it may be part of my learning in future. But I am willing to understand why there is a difference.

Comment: You can find some more information in [Class vs. Type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958961/class-vs-type-in-python)