# Query on type() in Python

Tags: python

When I run the following, I got the output as below:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(type(x))

y = "PYTHON"
print(type(y))
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
```

I have read that everything in Python is a `object`, yet I am seeing the output as `class`. I also read that `object` is a `class`. How can an object be a class? I am beginner in python and was unable to understand this. Can you please help me?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class vs. Type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958961/class-vs-type-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `type` function is to give you the class of a given object, not the type of the instantiated object.

See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: That doesn't explain the difference between "the class of a given object" and "type of the instantiated object"

Comment: @AviKaminetzky - I understand your analogy in terms of difference between class and an instance, but that doesn't appear to be what your initial statement is comparing

Answer (score 0):

An object is an instance of a class. `type` is identifying the class of which this object is an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

What you are saying is correct. Both `x` and `y` are objects.

The function "type" basically tells you about what is the type of the object.

As `x` is a list it's of ***list*** type. And same goes for `y`.