# Data types and classes

Tags: python, class, types

What is the exact difference between class and data types?
For checking the data type in Python, we used type(). For example we have a boolean data type, this will display <class 'bool'> in the console. Are they the same thing?

Comment: This is a clone of this thread [Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958961/class-vs-type-in-python)

Comment: They’re mostly the same thing.  When you’re discussing types more abstractly (like in a static typechecking context) then the terms get less interchangeable — eg a “union type” refers to one of multiple classes, and a “generic type” is parameterized so it can refer to a class that’s used in a particular way, and “type variables” are variables that can refer to arbitrary other types within certain bounds.  But if you talk about the type of a particular concrete object at runtime, yes, that’s always a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the type() function in Python, it returns the data type of the object you pass to it. For example, if you use type(True), it will return <class 'bool'>, indicating that the data type of True is a boolean.
In the case of built-in data types like booleans, type() actually returns the class that represents that data type. The bool class in Python represents boolean values. So, in a way, the data type and the class are connected. The class defines the data type and provides the implementation for working with objects of that type.