# Inconsistency on module in IPython

Tags: class, module, ipython

IPython seems inconsistent here:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '3.10.11 (main, May 16 2023, 00:28:57) [GCC 11.2.0]'

In [4]: type(sys)
Out[4]: module

In [5]: type(module)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 type(module)

NameError: name 'module' is not defined

In [6]: type(type(sys))
Out[6]: type
```

How can something that is not defined be a type and have a type?

I found this after discovering that no class `module` exists, although, if I import some module of mine, it automatically inherits attributes

```
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
```

What are these attributes inherited from?

Comment: I found this link talking about attributes of modules: https://peps.python.org/pep-0451/

Comment: "This PEP proposes to add a new class to importlib.machinery called “ModuleSpec”".  `import importlib.machinery;importlib.machinery.__file__`, I look at file content and find `from ._bootstrap import ModuleSpec`. Running this in Python: `mportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: I did not find it in my system but there it is https://pykaldi.github.io/_modules/importlib/_bootstrap.html.

Comment: Theoretically, taking type of type leads to metaclass and some sort of paradox may be expected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python?rq=2

Comment: cpython has implementation detail of module object: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4426279a4399158027a1145cff1c4c92424bf5b5/Objects/moduleobject.c#L109

Comment: Can you check `type(module)` in cpython?  I may install cpython as well but it would take more time.

Answer (score 1):

Although `sys.version` returns Python version number, I realize that I am using IPython (version 8.14.0 from `ipython --version` in the Unix command line.)

The situation differs in Python:

```
>>> import sys;sys.version
'3.10.11 (main, May 16 2023, 00:28:57) [GCC 11.2.0]'
>>> type(sys)
<class 'module'>
>>> type(type(sys))
<class 'type'>
>>> typesys=type(sys)
>>> typesys
<class 'module'>
>>> type(typesys)
<class 'type'>
>>> dir(typesys)
['__annotations__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', 
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', 
'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']

>>>help(typesys)
Help on class module in module builtins:

class module(object)
 |  module(name, doc=None)
 |  
 |  Create a module object.
 |  
 |  The name must be a string; the optional doc argument can have any type.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __delattr__(self, name, /)
 |      Implement delattr(self, name).
 |
```

**Answer to the first question**

Python wraps `type` value:

```
>>> type(2)
<class 'int'>
```

so that it takes less space but does not refer to an object:

```
>>> <class 'int'>
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    <class 'int'>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is confusing at first since everything is supposed to be an object in Python but the same occurs when defining a function:

```
>>> def f1(x):return x
>>> f1
<function f1 at 0x7f3df38f88b0>
```

Even more confusing, IPython does not show any wrapper.

Hence, `type(2)` does not evaluate to `<class 'int'>`) but `int`, which refers to an object by accident with respect to most classes.  `import(sys);type(sys)` evaluates to `module` which does not refer to an object.  Same with `function`:

```
In [3]: def f1(x):return x

In [4]: type(f1)
Out[4]: function

In [5]: function
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 function

NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

The wrapped object can be accessed by naming:

```
>>> typeint=type(int)
>>> import sys;typesys=type(sys)
>>> (typeint,typesys)
(<class 'type'>, <class 'module'>)
```

It occurs that `int, function, module` are normal names in Python or iPython (`int=4` does not throw an error).

One way to fix IPython is simply `import sys;module=type(sys)` so that `type(module)` works nicely like `type(int)` although now `module` has this apparently confusing behaviour:

```
In [7]: module
Out[7]: module
```

like

```
In [1]: int
Out[1]: int
```

**Partial answer to the second question**

The class module exists.  `help(type(sys))`works.

Probably, it has many subclasses, possibly ModuleSpec, though I can't prove it.

**Difference between type and class**

When type is applied twice (or more, on any object) it always evaluates to the class type.

```
>>> type(type(1))
<class 'type'>
```

In Python 2.7 `type(type(1))` or `type(type(sys))` evaluates to `<type 'type'>`.  In Python ≥ 2.7, type and class have no semantic difference.

Alternative syntax:

```
>>> int.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

Type or class is a member of itself:

```
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(type)==type
True
>>> type(type) is type
True
>>> isinstance(type,type)
True
```

`class` can be used to define a class:

```
>>> class object:pass
```

`type` with functional syntax can also be used with 3 parameters to define a class (see `help(type)`).

See also

- [Class vs. Type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958961/class-vs-type-in-python)
- [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python?rq=2)